# How would I fix 'has no exported member'

Tags: typescript

Creating my own functions but as soon I import the module that I created in another file it will error while I have already exported the class the function is in.

I have already tried a lot of the similar problems to mine but it doesn't seem to work... maybe its just my dev environment

**chiFunctions.ts**

```
    export class ChiFunctions {
            public Arrivederci() {
                    const time: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
                    let statements: string[] = ['good-night', 'Good Morning','Good-afternoon'];

                    if (time > '12:00:00 pm')
                            return statements[1];
                    else if (time < '12:00:00 pm')
                            return statements[2];
            }
    }
```

**chiListener.ts**

```
    import { Arrivederci } from 'utils/chiFunctions'; // Here is the error
```

**What's supposed to happen**

```
console.log(`${Arrivederci}`);
```

*OUTPUT*

```
Good-afternoon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two issues with your code:

- You're exporting the class, not the function.
- You're not actually calling the function.

You'd need to do something like this to get your current code to work:

```
import { ChiFunctions } from 'utils/chiFunctions';
const functions = new ChiFunctions();
console.log(`${functions.Arrivederci()}`);
```

You could make this a little cleaner by using a [static method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties), which would be callable without creating an instance of the `ChiFunctions` class, but that's still a bit messy.

While in languages like C# and Java, everything has to be wrapped in classes, there is no such limitation in JavaScript/TypeScript - you can remove a lot of this boilerplate by just exporting the function from your `chiFunctions` file:

```
export function Arrivederci() {
    const time: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    let statements: string[] = ['good-night', 'Good Morning','Good-afternoon'];

    if (time > '12:00:00 pm')
        return statements[1];
    else if (time < '12:00:00 pm')
        return statements[2];
}
```

And then you can do:

```
import { Arrivederci } from 'utils/chiFunctions';
console.log(`${Arrivederci()}`);
```

Which is almost exactly your original code, just with the syntax fixed so that the function gets called!